# how do i write the following sql query in Lambda expression

Tags: asp.net-mvc, lambda, ef-code-first

how do i write the following sql query in Lambda expression.

```
select rating from ratingtable where movieId=@movieid and userid=@userid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean in LINQ?  Like this:

```
var movieId = 3902;  // use valid movie ID
var userId = 5802;   // use valid user ID
ratingtable.Where( x => x.movieId==movieId && x.userid==userId )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from rt in ratingtable.Where(rt => rt.movieId == movie && rt.userid == user)
select rt
```

This is a great place to start as well for simple queries:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b